# Test progress with a promise notify for $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload for my file uploads. It provides a `progress` method that is called, when the xhr requests receives the `progress` event. This is from the source code of angular-file-upload:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    deferred.notify(e);
}, false);
```

My problem is now, how should I test this using `$httpBackend`? I can test the success and error methods with

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST("http://localhost:9001/").respond('ok');
$httpBackend.expectPOST("http://localhost:9001/").respond(500, 'some error');
```

but I can't get the `notify` of the promise to fire. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

The part that I want to test, is inside the `progress` method:

```
    $upload.http({url: url, method: 'POST', data: file})
    .progress(function(evt) {

      // here is more code, that needs to be tested

      self.$deferreds.upload.notify((100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total).toFixed(2));
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      self.$deferreds.upload.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(response) {
      self.$deferreds.upload.reject(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to spy on the `$upload.http` method and return a mocked object that lets you register progress, success and error callbacks.

```
spyOn($upload, 'http').andReturn({
  progress: function (progressCallback) {
    this.progressCallback = progressCallback;
  },
  success: function (errorCallback) {
    this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
  },
  error: function (errorCallback) {
    this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
  }
});
```

Then you can call these callbacks synchronously in the tests:

```
it('should do something', function () {
  $upload.progressCallback();
  // or $upload.successCallback();
  // or $upload.errorCallback();

  expect('this').toBe('that');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We are speaking about unit-tests?

Why do you need to test 3rd-party at all?

Just **mock this all part**.

Probably I did not get the idea of the question, so need more code that should be covered by tests.

Comment: I've added more code from my application. I want to test my code that gets executed when the progress event is fired.